# get_node method is not called

Tags: graphene-python, graphene-django

I am experiencing an issue with `get_node`  method in a django object type definition. The method doesn't seem to be called in my case.

I even tried debugging with `pdb` by pausing execution inside the `get_node` method, didn't work either.

This is a sample of my code

```
class DocumentGQL(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Document
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node,)

    @classmethod
    def get_node(cls, info, id):
        logger.info(id)
        ...

class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    document = graphene.relay.Node.Field(DocumentGQL)
```

And console output
`"POST /graphql/ HTTP/1.1" 200 26`

Graphql Query

```
{
  document(id:"e551a1e5-6fae-47c2-be87-3feeb802bf7f"){
    description
    id
  }
}
```

Graphql output

```
{
  "data": {
    "document": null
  }
}
```

I believe I followed the [docs](https://docs.graphene-python.org/projects/django/en/latest/authorization/#filtering-id-based-node-access) when doing this. Am I missing something? Kindly assist.

Comment: same problem here. did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `id` you are passing to the query. Somewhere in the [docs](https://docs.graphene-python.org/en/latest/relay/nodes/#quick-example), is buried this little note:

> The `id` returned by the `Ship` type when you query it will be a scalar
> which contains enough info for the server to know its type and its id.
>
> For example, the **instance `Ship(id=1)` will return `U2hpcDox` as the id
> when you query it (which is the base64 encoding of `Ship:1`)**, and which
> could be useful later if we want to query a node by its id.

So basically if the `id` of your document is `e551a1e5-6fae-47c2-be87-3feeb802bf7f`, then the proper way to do the query is to supply, an id of `RG9jdW1lbnQ6ZTU1MWExZTUtNmZhZS00N2MyLWJlODctM2ZlZWI4MDJiZjdm` in the query. Of course the above is simply the output of:

```sh
printf 'Document:e551a1e5-6fae-47c2-be87-3feeb802bf7f' | base64
```

I hope that helps. I was just in the same boat as you.